# Crop inserted PDF page - permanently

Tags: positioning, crop

I'd like to include a part of another PDF in my LaTeX document. I've found parameters for "includeimage" in another StackExchange answer which would work in theory:

```
\includegraphics[clip, trim=0.5cm 11cm 0.5cm 11cm, width=1.00\textwidth]{gfx/BI-yourfile.pdf}
```

However, the author who wrote that answer stated that the rest of the PDF is still invisibly included in the output. I don't want that. The rest of the included PDF can include sensitive information, I just want the cropped part to be stored in the PDF.

I'd like to avoid having to manually crop the PDF (with pdfcrop or something), as the needed crop margins are being calculated by a LaTeX function depending on the document content(s), so I can't easily pre-crop the PDF to be included.

I found other answers with other methods, but nowhere did it explicitly state that the content I've cropped away is definitely not included in the final PDF.

Comment: even with pdfcrop I don't think that you can be sure that the cropped text is not still there internally.

Comment: I tried an experiment where I copied a trimmed one page PDF.  The original was 21.5 KB and the result was 20.3 KB.  So while it was smaller, it wasn't much smaller (considering the part copied was only 0.5in by 3in).  Viewing the PDFs as ASCII showed large stream objects.  The original started `<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 949>>stream` and the copy started `<<
/Length1 1903
/Length2 14736
/Length3 0
/Length 15914     
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream`

Comment: The only reliable method is to convert the one PDF page to a raster image (such as PNG), remove metadata (if any), and place it as a raster image. The file will be large, but maybe not too large. Resolution should be OK if image is as 600dpi, possibly OK at 300dpi if no fine print.

Comment: I repeated my experiment by converting the original to PNG (22.6 KB).  The copy was 31.4 KB!  I think we can safely conclude that the resulting PDFs do include the entire image.

Comment: Trimming the PNG with GIMP reduced the final PDF to 9.74 KB.

Comment: If you have access to Adobe Acrobat Pro: First, extract the one page you need, as its own PDF file. Then "examine document" finds metadata and allows you to remove it. After that, you can safely place the page in your TeX PDF.

Comment: @RobtA Only if nothing on that page is sensitive.

Comment: That's the problem, the rest of that one page contains sensitive data, too, and I was looking for a LaTeX-only solution, without having to manually edit the PDF with other tools. Can I use LaTeX to automatically convert the cropped area into PNG? There is no text that needs to stay as text in that PDF, a PNG image would be OK.

Comment: @cfr Adobe Acrobat Pro also lets you "redact" sensitive information on any page. However, the surest method is to convert the page to an image, remove its image metadata, then white-out what you don't want others to see.